# KendoUI TreeView Dynamic JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm attempting to use the KendoUI by Telerik and get a treeview to bind to dynamic JSON from a generic handler.

In my generic handler, I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to convert a List to my JSON results, which works just great and even works with a different KendoUI control (charts).

Here is what I have as far as the javascript to build the treeview:

```
var treeSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "Services/CategoryHandler.ashx",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        type: "GET"
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: treeSource
            });
```

Here is a shortened example of the returned JSON:

```
[
   {
      "text":"Node 1",
      "expanded":true,
      "items":null
   },
   {
      "text":"Node 2",
      "expanded":true,
      "items":null
   }
]
```

"items" will be sub collections in the tree.

When I add the items directly to the datasource such as:

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                            dataSource: [
                                { text: "Item 1", expanded: true, items: [
                                    { text: "Item 1.1" },
                                    { text: "Item 1.2" },
                                    { text: "Item 1.3" }
                                ] },
                                { text: "Item 2", items: [
                                    { text: "Item 2.1" },
                                    { text: "Item 2.2" },
                                    { text: "Item 2.3" }
                                ] },
                                { text: "Item 3" }
                            ]
                        })
```

It works just fine. It just does not work when I call a service which writes out the JSON, and what I mean by it does not work, is no data shows up, it is blank.

Any thoughts to what I might be missing or guidance to how I can verify my data is even being returned from the service and even filling my DataSource properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IMPORTANT** As November 8th, 2012 KendoUI already supports it.

The Kendo TreeView does not support binding to a data source yet. The good news is that this is in the plans and will be implemented soon (next release).

Comment: Okay thanks. I found a workaround where I did an $.ajax GET and used the string results to bind to the tree view. I'm looking forward to KendoUI updates :) Thanks again.

Comment: Does the KendoUI Grid bind to a HttpHandler?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with a trick. I am using the dynamic ViewBag with Json serialized at the controller and therefore, nodes are being drawn great.

My issue is that the events don't seem to work ok. For instance I want to catch the onDrop and rise an alert to show the actual values of such node, and instead it displays the text for ALL nodes. This is driving me crazy by the way.

This is my code, hope can help someone.

```
    function onDrop(e) {
        alert(treeView.text(e.sourceNode));
    }
```

A Template must be assigned in order to work:

```
template: "<span rel='#= item.Id #'> #=item.text #</span>",
```